# Get dimensions of 2D array with respect to size of 1D array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have one dimensional array like this

```
$arr=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'......'21');
```

From this i want to create a two dimensional array look like this.

[image]

The dimension of the 2D array is depends on the number of elements in the 1D array.

**Conditions**

1.The number of rows of 2D array is fixed as 5.

2.The number of columns may vary.

3.Third row will be empty except for the last element

**NOTE**

Size of the one dimensional array is varied.

We need to get the dimension of 2D array also how can i print it?

**UPDATE**

Here is my code

```
$k=0;
$l=0;
$i=0;
$A=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
//size of 1D array
$size=count($arr);
//2D array
$B=[];
$x=?;//no of columns of 2d array
$y=5;//no of rows of 2d array

for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){

        $B[k][l]=$A[i];
        $k++;

        if($k==2 && $l!=$x){
                $k++;

        }
        if($k==4){
                $l++;
        }

}
```

How can i get the value of `$x` it is columns size of 2D array

Comment: what you tried till now.? put your code effort?

Comment: Let me update my code.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem

Comment: @Asperon may be its simple  a homework for you:)

Comment: "3.Third row will be empty except for the last element". You mean, last column? And what if the last column is not fully completed?

Comment: Yes your assumptions are correct

Comment: The only way to keep a perfect 5 in each column is to always have n*4 + 1 items. Ie. 5 or 9 or 13 or 17 or 21. Etc. Is that intended?

Comment: yes it can reach up to 49, 53 , 57  etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (Edit: Array solution also added below)
Instead of the 1D array I have used a loop which emulates an array.

Assumptions : if there is any item in the last column (e.g sample input 10) the second last column will have a * regardless of the items reaching upto row 3 or not.

```
$itemCount = 49;

$residual = $itemCount % 4;

$starCount = ceil($itemCount/4);

if ($residual > 1) {
    $starCount -= 1;
} else if ($residual) {
    $starCount -= 2;
}



$itemsArray = [];
$key = 0;
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $itemCount ; $i++ ) {
     $key = $key % 5 ;  // fixing the offset and row number
     if ($key == 2 && $starCount) {
         $itemsArray[$key][] = '*';
         $starCount--;
     $key++;
         $itemsArray[$key][] = $i;
     } else {
         $itemsArray[$key][] = $i;
     }  
    $key++; 

}

print_r($itemsArray); //check output
```

Tested for 21, 49, 50, 51. Will show Stars 1 less than number of columns as mentioned in assumption.( it can be changed if you want by changing the residual check count)

Note: I am leaving the printing part as that is upto you(you want to print it on the command line or on a web page). Moreover its just a matter of looping over the result.
And for the array version of this code you can put

`$itemCount = count($yourArray);`

replace the for loop with `foreach ($yourArray as $i)` (or change $i with something meaningful all over.)

Output

21

```
1  5  9  13 17 
2  6  10 14 18 
*  *  *  *  19 
3  7  11 15 20 
4  8  12 16 21
```

49

```
1  5  9  13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 45 
2  6  10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 42 46 
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  47 
3  7  11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43 48 
4  8  12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 49
```

50

```
1  5  9  13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 45 49 
2  6  10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 42 46 50 
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
3  7  11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43 47 
4  8  12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48
```

51

```
1  5  9  13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 45 49 
2  6  10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 42 46 50 
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  51
3  7  11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43 47 
4  8  12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48
```

Array based solution for reference:

```
<?php

$itemCount = 21;


$array = range(1,$itemCount);// the 1D array 
$residual = $itemCount % 4;

$starCount = ceil($itemCount/4);

if ($residual > 1) {
    $starCount -= 1;
} else if ($residual) {
    $starCount -= 2;
}



$itemsArray = [];
$key = 0;
foreach ($array as $i) {
     $key = $key % 5 ;  // fixing the offset and row number
     if ($key == 2 && $starCount) {
         $itemsArray[$key][] = '*';
         $starCount--;
     $key++;
         $itemsArray[$key][] = $i;
     } else {
         $itemsArray[$key][] = $i;
     }
    $key++;

}

print_r($itemsArray); //check output
```

Comment: when `$itemCount =49`  second last and last columns has elements in third row

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to generate the desired grid structure. This method is applicable to any arbitrary sized array.

## Updated code:

```
$arr = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10', '11');

$arrLength = count($arr);
$columns = ceil($arrLength / 4);
$rows = ($columns == 1) ? (($arrLength > 2) ? $arrLength + 1 : $arrLength) : 5;

echo "Grid dimension: " . $rows . " x " . $columns . "<br />"; 

$output_array = array();
$index = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $columns; ++$i){
    for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j){
        if($j == 2 && ($i != $columns - 1 || $columns == 1)){
            $output_array[$j][$i] = "*";
            continue;
        }
        $output_array[$j][$i] = isset($arr[$index]) ? $arr[$index] : "";
        ++$index;
    }
}

// display $output_array
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; ++$i){
    for($j = 0; $j < $columns; ++$j){
        echo $output_array[$i][$j] . " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
Grid dimension: 5 x 3
1 5 9
2 6 10
* * 11
3 7
4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for any array of any length:

```
<?php
$arr=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21');
$len=count($arr);
$key=0;
$rows=5;
$cols=floor(($len - 2)/4) + 1;
for ($j=0;$j<$cols;$j++)
    for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++)                    
        if ($i==2 && $j!=$cols-1) {
            $arr2D[$i][$j] = '*';
        } else {        
            $arr2D[$i][$j] = $key>=$len ? "" : $arr[$key++];
        } 
//print array
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0;$j<$cols;$j++)    
        echo "<td width='30px'>" . $arr2D[$i][$j] . "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

output:

```
1   5   9   13  17
2   6   10  14  18
*   *   *   *   19
3   7   11  15  20
4   8   12  16  21
```